# Can I use @next/env package in next.config.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am wanting to access the env config from `next.config.js` in order to surface some env vars set in .env.local and set some server runtime config based on them.

Is it reasonable in `next.config.js` to do...

```
const { loadEnvConfig } = require("@next/env");
const env = loadEnvConfig(".").combinedEnv;
```

It works, but I can't find any docs that explain how to do this, or if it's a supported package/api.

Comment: You can use `loadEnvConfig` from `@next/env` to load the environment variables the same way Next.js does. It's the recommended way to load env vars for tests as mentioned in [Test Environment Variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#test-environment-variables) documentation. I don't see why you couldn't also use it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As documented here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#test-environment-variables

When you run loadEnvConfig it actually updates process.env to include config that next js uses, so this should work...

```
const { loadEnvConfig } = require("@next/env");
loadEnvConfig(".")
// process.env.SOMETHING <~~ includes value of SOMETHING set in .env.local
```

Comment: Thanks @juliomalves